# Telegram only runs with sudo

Tags: sudo, telegram

I don't know why, but I can only run Telegram with sudo. I just downloaded the tar from desktop.telegram.com and extracted its contents in /usr/local/Telegram.

I can now open the program with:

```
sudo /usr/local/Telegram/Telegram
```

but not with

```
/usr/local/Telegram/Telegram
```

If I do the second one, I get an error log:

```
[2016.10.31 12:53:39] Launched version: 10019, alpha: [FALSE], beta: 0, debug mode: [FALSE], test dc: [FALSE]
[2016.10.31 12:53:39] Executable dir: , name: 
[2016.10.31 12:53:39] Initial working dir: /home/iguarna/
[2016.10.31 12:53:39] Working dir: /home/iguarna/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/
[2016.10.31 12:53:39] Arguments: "Telegram"
[2016.10.31 12:53:39] FATAL: Could not open '/home/iguarna/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/log_startXX.txt' for writing log!
[2016.10.31 12:53:39] Connecting local socket to /tmp/95578c71afe4942c16be0fb6f3bfa82f-{87A94AB0-E370-4cde-98D3-ACC110C5967D}...
[2016.10.31 12:53:39] This is the only instance of Telegram, starting server and app...
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: I downloaded the compiled filed from Telgram's website. I edited my question for clarification. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. It is still the same. If I a reboot my system and try to run the app again, it throws an error log. It looks as if for some reason Telegram is expecting admin privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message `FATAL: Could not open '/home/iguarna/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/log_startXX.txt' for writing log!` shows that you did run `telegram` as `root`, and it created the log file (as `root`), now, the regular user cannot write to the `root`-owned log file. Fix this by:

```
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) /home/iguarna/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/log_startXX.txt
```

Where you run a program from is immaterial. Who you run a program as is important.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. But the file simply does not exist

Comment: Then the problem is directory ownership. Fix it with `sudo chown -R $(id -u:$(id -g) /home/iguarna/.local/` and don't run graphics tools as `root`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much. You missed one parenthesis. It should be sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) /home/iguarna/.local/ . I am accepting your answer.

Comment: waltinator has the correct solution. When i did this Telegram started working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Put your file in `/usr/bin` not `/usr/local` and not the whole folder JUST the telegram executable and then run

`Telegram`

It starts up for me on 16.04 this way, also, keep that `updater` script somewhere safe for later.

[image]

Comment: Ok. Just to learn: why is this??
\

Comment: That is where executable files go, a user can then run them without sudo, like an installed application.

Comment: You could not run it from /usr/local because your user does not have the right to run fiels from that folder.